# Convert rank scores to probabilities

Tags: ranking

I have a LightGBM ranking model that outputs real-valued scores given a set of feature vectors. The model essentially ranks the feature vectors.

The problem is that the model outputs are real-valued and can change from model to model (if re-trained). The scores can be even negative!
The relative distances between scores are of main interest.

The idea is that good ranking will have great separation between scores of top #1 and top #2, and the rest.

I am looking for a procedure that would compute a confidence value (between 0 and 1) for each feature vector.

Large separation of scores => high confidence

Small separation of scores => low confidence

Comment: I came across a similar problem and found this post. Did you find solution to this ? I would appreciate if you can share your thoughts on this. Thanks
AK

Comment: Soft max I believe transforms things are not looking like a probability density into a probability density. I think it would have the result that you are asking in it when you have a linear output and two of them are close together and they are less likely to be different and when they are further apart the probability itself also be very different.